# How to decline a Job upgrade without looking suspicious?

Tags: job-change

I have to work out a tricky situation regarding my employment.

Since the beginning of May I am employed to hiring agency A and allocated to work externally at company B. I don't enjoy this work I am going to look for a new job in the fall. I only took this job because I was allowed to go on vacation for 3 weeks in September, despite the fact that usually that much vacation wouldn't be allowed so early.

Company B is one of the largest companies in the country. Yesterday my superior asked me if I would be interessted to start working at company B directly, because they need to cut down on external personnel by the end of the year.

Since that contract would be 'all in' I would earn more and also get some aditional features like bonus payments. Company A would get compensation from company B.

From my supervisors' perspective this must look like a win win situation for all parties. But with my intention to quit in the fall, there are some finacial downsides for me so I rather won't change company.

What's my play here, to not look too suspicious when declining the offer and not to get cut right away?

Comment: What is the financial downside here?

Comment: keep in mind that you may not find a new job immediately when you start looking in the fall...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Strongly consider the bird in the hand - moving forward with Company B's job offer.

You can't predict what will happen in fall.  Perhaps you will find that, as a permanent employee, your job has changed such that you like it. Or you may find other opportunities within the same company that you do like.

If in fall (right after your 3 week vacation?) you do still want to quit, try sticking around while doing a job search instead. You will then still **have** a job which removes a lot of pressure will looking for a new job, and you will be a more desirable candidate for a new job.

Comment: This is a good answer. You can't predict what will happen. Also, being a regular employee makes it much easier to start talking with your boss about changing or expanding your job role, to let you do work that you find more fulfilling/interesting.